# Alert pop up with LWUIT

Tags: java-me, popup, alert, lwuit

How to create the pop up window using LWUIT? I want to show an alert and that alert automatically dispose after 5 to 10 sec's.  How to do this with LWUIT?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this code and show the alert some periodic time.

```
        Dialog validDialog = new Dialog("Alert");
        validDialog.setScrollable(false);
        validDialog.setIsScrollVisible(false);
        validDialog.setTimeout(5000); // set timeout milliseconds
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea("...."); //pass the alert text here
        textArea.setFocusable(false);
        textArea.setIsScrollVisible(false);
        validDialog.addComponent(textArea);
        validDialog.show(0, 100, 10, 10, true);
```